# Aurelia project has problems starting on iPad: Can't find variable: Notification

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari, aurelia

When running aurelia application on iPad it does not opens and here is the error log:

```
> [Warning] WARN [templating-binding-language] – "Detected string
> literal in let bindings. Did you mean
> \"activeSection.bind=formBuilder\" or \"activeSection=${formBuilder}\"
> ?" (vendor.aurelia.bdf35799438e6ae7bf5e.chunk.js, line 28)
>     [Warning] WARN [templating-binding-language] – "Detected string literal in let bindings. Did you mean
> \"activeSection.bind=formBuilder\" or \"activeSection=${formBuilder}\"
> ?" (vendor.aurelia.338a8c7144d9a8345cf3.chunk.js, line 28)
>     [Info] Can not register forbidden callback (app.b3472b60b2555a61247e.bundle.js, line 1)
>     [Info] INFO [aurelia] – "Aurelia Started" (vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js, line 28)
>     [Info] INFO [SocketTask] – "Initialize client socket" (vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js, line 28)
>     [Error] ERROR [app-lifecycle] – "Failed to set root app" – Error: Error invoking e. Check the inner error for details.
>     ------------------------------------------------
>     Inner Error:
>     Message: Can't find variable: Notification
>     Inner Error Stack:
>     get@<server_path>/app.b3472b60b2555a61247e.bundle.js:1:69855
>     e@<server_path>/app.b3472b60b2555a61247e.bundle.js:1:69711
>     invoke@<server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:74768
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:78066
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:69754
>     F@<server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:74579
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:78066
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:36867
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:65078
>     Ae@<server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:38992
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:41786
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:65282
>     d@<server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:83939
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57340
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63629
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63970
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58254
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63629
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63970
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58254
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63629
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63970
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58254
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63629
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63970
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58254
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     h@<server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:12444
>     f@<server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:12369
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:13889
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:12122
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:73577
>     End Inner Error Stack
>     ------------------------------------------------
>      — vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:27
>     Error: Error invoking e. Check the inner error for details.
>     ------------------------------------------------
>     Inner Error:
>     Message: Can't find variable: Notification
>     Inner Error Stack:
>     get@<server_path>/app.b3472b60b2555a61247e.bundle.js:1:69855
>     e@<server_path>/app.b3472b60b2555a61247e.bundle.js:1:69711
>     invoke@<server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:74768
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:78066
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:69754
>     F@<server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:74579
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:78066
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:36867
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:65078
>     Ae@<server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:38992
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:41786
>     <server_path>/vendor.aurelia-templating.6366b3b873c709a8df96.chunk.js:1:65282
>     d@<server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:83939
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57340
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63629
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63970
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58254
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63629
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63970
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58254
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57506
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58161
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63629
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63970
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58254
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:59220
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63629
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:63970
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58254
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58849
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60202
>     h@<server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:12444
>     f@<server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:12369
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:13889
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:12122
>     <server_path>/vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:73577
>     End Inner Error Stack
>     ------------------------------------------------
>      — vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:27r — aurelia-pal.js:30(anonymous function) —
> aurelia-dependency-injection.js:676(anonymous function) —
> aurelia-dependency-injection.js:29F —
> aurelia-dependency-injection.js:420(anonymous function) —
> aurelia-dependency-injection.js:674(anonymous function) —
> aurelia-templating.js:2265(anonymous function) —
> aurelia-templating.js:4338Ae — aurelia-templating.js:2430(anonymous
> function) — aurelia-templating.js:2651(anonymous function) —
> aurelia-templating.js:4350d — bluebird.js:5382(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3377(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3431(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3468(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3558(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3487(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3390(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3431(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3468(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3558(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3487(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3390(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3431(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3468(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3558(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3487(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3390(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3431(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3468(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3558(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3487(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3769(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3814(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3435(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3468(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3558(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3487(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3769(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3814(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3435(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3468(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3558(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3487(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3390(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3431(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3468(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3558(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3487(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3390(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3431(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3468(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3558(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3487(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3390(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3431(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3468(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3558(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3487(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3769(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3814(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3435(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3468(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3558(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3487(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3769(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:3814(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3435(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:3468(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:3558h —
> bluebird.js:161f — bluebird.js:153(anonymous function) —
> bluebird.js:272(anonymous function) — bluebird.js:120(anonymous
> function) — bluebird.js:4724
>       (anonymous function) (vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:28:123416)
>       (anonymous function) (vendor.aurelia.6b531a1070ffb345a67a.chunk.js:1:9713)
>       (anonymous function) (app.b3472b60b2555a61247e.bundle.js:1:16339)
>       (anonymous function) (app.b3472b60b2555a61247e.bundle.js:1:15014)
>       s (app.b3472b60b2555a61247e.bundle.js:1:13904)
>       d (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:83940)
>       (anonymous function) (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:57341)
>       (anonymous function) (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58162)
>       (anonymous function) (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:58850)
>       (anonymous function) (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:60092)
>       h (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:12445)
>       f (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:12370)
>       (anonymous function) (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:13890)
>       (anonymous function) (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:12123)
>       (anonymous function) (vendor.9dbde53055f93a8a4679.chunk.js:2089:73578)
```

Do you know how to fix it? Maybe some polyfills required? Added full log that I received from the user that had problems with application.Not sure what the "Notification" is and why it causes problems (some aurelia library maybe)? Application works on other browsers and on latest versions of Safari on MacBook.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not enough information here.  Near as I can tell, that's not even a valid aurelia error message. Does the application work on other browsers?

Comment: Yes, it works on other browsers and on latest versions of Safari on MacBook. I've attached full version of the log that I received from the iPad user that had problems with application.